# SQL Dynamic Pivot based on another column

Tags: sql-server, pivot, row-number

I have the below query

```
SELECT TOP 10
    pkRowId AS [Row Guid],
    fkItemId AS [Item Guid],
    SortOrder AS [SortOrder],
    IsMain,
    Updated,
    REPLACE(Url, 'i.ebayimg.com', 'ecx-images.amazon.com') AS [Url],
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY fkItemId ORDER BY SortOrder) AS [Row Number]
FROM 
    [download].[item_image]
```

which displays data in the below format:

[image: Input]

which I would like to be displayed in the following format:

[image: Result]

How can I pivot my source so that `Url1` displays the Url where IsMain is `true`?

Comment: This has been asked and answered hundreds and hundreds of times. Do none of the duplicates for this work for you? Also using string literals as column alias has been deprecated for quite some time. And you really shouldn't add spaces. It makes things more difficult. https://sqlblog.org/2012/01/23/bad-habits-to-kick-using-as-instead-of-for-column-aliases

Comment: You can start from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10404348/sql-server-dynamic-pivot-query)

Comment: @SeanLange Spaces were added for readibility. Also, it's not necessary that everyone has the permissions to run `%:Deprecated Features`.

Comment: Not sure I understand what you mean about deprecated features. Using strings as aliases has been deprecated for a long time. Pretty sure since sql 2005. As for the task at hand, did you find an example of this?